# Sticky Navigation bar from the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create a navigation bar that begins at the bottom of the page and then as the user scrolls it sticks to the top for sometime now with very little success. The idea is something similar to [This website (http://grovemade.com)](http://grovemade.com)

Please could someone assist or point me in the right direction as to what html and css is required to achieve this?

If you take a look at [my website](http://test.engrazzle.com) the second navigation bar has been implemented using the code example provided below. It is just which values need to be modified to modify where and when the navigation bar sticks to the top of the page

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you. Josh

Comment: What have you tried? Google is where you want to start. Search for jquery fixed div on scroll, or something similar.

Comment: I've managed to achieve this for a normal sticky navigation bar, however trying to achieve this from the bottom of the page seems to lead to a dead end and Google finds it hard to give the answer for what I'm actually trying to achieve.

Comment: you will definitely need jQuery for this(or pure JS), create bar with absolute position at the bottom of the page, then add `scroll` event on window, where you will chcek position of scrollbar according to your bar( scrolltop - window height - navigation bar height) then make your navigation fixed with `top:0`

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called **Sticky Nav**. Do you want something like this?

```js
$(function () {
  ht = $("h3").offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop() > ht);
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > ht)
      $("h3").addClass("fixed");
    else
      $("h3").removeClass("fixed");
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
p, h3 {margin-bottom: 10px; line-height: 1.5;}
h3 {text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 1px 0;}
h3.fixed {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: #fff; right: 0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe dolore explicabo quo possimus accusantium doloremque necessitatibus pariatur, natus numquam beatae, dignissimos quisquam illum voluptas eos et velit, consequuntur eligendi totam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum iusto nemo nisi eum necessitatibus, eaque ratione tempora fuga! Molestias repellendus modi nostrum obcaecati, dignissimos, odit! Culpa voluptatem iste, illo totam!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur nostrum ratione unde et non minima animi, cum ut vero, voluptatem quia facere facilis libero nobis eaque ab pariatur recusandae commodi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus aperiam officia corporis, modi ea. Non voluptatum, molestiae in soluta a ipsa iusto aut. Alias possimus praesentium architecto aperiam, porro maxime.</p>
    <h3>This would become fixed soon!</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe dolore explicabo quo possimus accusantium doloremque necessitatibus pariatur, natus numquam beatae, dignissimos quisquam illum voluptas eos et velit, consequuntur eligendi totam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum iusto nemo nisi eum necessitatibus, eaque ratione tempora fuga! Molestias repellendus modi nostrum obcaecati, dignissimos, odit! Culpa voluptatem iste, illo totam!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur nostrum ratione unde et non minima animi, cum ut vero, voluptatem quia facere facilis libero nobis eaque ab pariatur recusandae commodi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus aperiam officia corporis, modi ea. Non voluptatum, molestiae in soluta a ipsa iusto aut. Alias possimus praesentium architecto aperiam, porro maxime.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe dolore explicabo quo possimus accusantium doloremque necessitatibus pariatur, natus numquam beatae, dignissimos quisquam illum voluptas eos et velit, consequuntur eligendi totam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum iusto nemo nisi eum necessitatibus, eaque ratione tempora fuga! Molestias repellendus modi nostrum obcaecati, dignissimos, odit! Culpa voluptatem iste, illo totam!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur nostrum ratione unde et non minima animi, cum ut vero, voluptatem quia facere facilis libero nobis eaque ab pariatur recusandae commodi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus aperiam officia corporis, modi ea. Non voluptatum, molestiae in soluta a ipsa iusto aut. Alias possimus praesentium architecto aperiam, porro maxime.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe dolore explicabo quo possimus accusantium doloremque necessitatibus pariatur, natus numquam beatae, dignissimos quisquam illum voluptas eos et velit, consequuntur eligendi totam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum iusto nemo nisi eum necessitatibus, eaque ratione tempora fuga! Molestias repellendus modi nostrum obcaecati, dignissimos, odit! Culpa voluptatem iste, illo totam!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur nostrum ratione unde et non minima animi, cum ut vero, voluptatem quia facere facilis libero nobis eaque ab pariatur recusandae commodi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus aperiam officia corporis, modi ea. Non voluptatum, molestiae in soluta a ipsa iusto aut. Alias possimus praesentium architecto aperiam, porro maxime.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe dolore explicabo quo possimus accusantium doloremque necessitatibus pariatur, natus numquam beatae, dignissimos quisquam illum voluptas eos et velit, consequuntur eligendi totam.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum iusto nemo nisi eum necessitatibus, eaque ratione tempora fuga! Molestias repellendus modi nostrum obcaecati, dignissimos, odit! Culpa voluptatem iste, illo totam!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur nostrum ratione unde et non minima animi, cum ut vero, voluptatem quia facere facilis libero nobis eaque ab pariatur recusandae commodi!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus aperiam officia corporis, modi ea. Non voluptatum, molestiae in soluta a ipsa iusto aut. Alias possimus praesentium architecto aperiam, porro maxime.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! it worked amazingly! what perimeters would have to be modified to adjust when the text sticks to the top of the page and where it attaches itself. you can see a live view of the site here if thats any help with what I'm trying to achieve? http://test.engrazzle.com

Comment: @josh2205 I am checking.

Comment: It is too fast... You need to check where you are adding it.